# Not able to run datastax-agent-5.1.3

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I am facing issues in running datastax-agent. I am getting the following error.

```
  INFO [main] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,076 Starting Jetty server: {:join? false, :ssl? false, :host nil, :port 61621}
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,117 Got new config from OpsCenter: {:kerberos_use_keytab true, :rollups300_ttl 2419200, :kerberos_use_ticket_cache true, :rollups60_ttl 604800, :thrift_user "", :thrift_port 9160, :ec2_metadata_api_host "169.254.169.254", :metrics_enabled 1, :rollups7200_ttl 31536000, :thrift_ssl_truststore nil, :metrics_ignored_column_families "", :cassandra_log_location "/var/log/cassandra/system.log", :thrift_rpc_interface "172.16.1.42", :thrift_ssl_truststore_password nil, :config_md5 "8c955eaf3c3fb61a60cf207e55f55672", :jmx_port 7199, :provisioning 0, :thrift_pass "", :use_ssl 0, :kerberos_debug false, :rollups86400_ttl -1, :api_port "61621", :storage_keyspace "OpsCenter", :kerberos_renew_tgt true, :metrics_ignored_solr_cores "", :thrift_ssl_truststore_type "JKS", :metrics_ignored_keyspaces "system, system_traces, system_auth, dse_auth, OpsCenter", :rollup_subscriptions [], :cassandra_install_location ""}
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,121 Starting up agent collection.
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,122 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,164 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [Jetty] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,170 Jetty server started
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,174 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,227 Starting OS metric collectors (Linux)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,236 Starting Cassandra JMX metric collectors
  INFO [install-location-finder] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,256 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [install-location-finder] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,294 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,314 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [install-location-finder] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,331 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,349 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
  INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,370 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
 ERROR [StompConnection receiver] 2015-06-10 10:57:18,529 Error getting all disk devices: Cannot run program "iostat": error=2, No such file or directory
  INFO [jmx-metrics-1] 2015-06-10 10:57:23,251 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
 ERROR [node-details-3] 2015-06-10 10:57:26,321 Error getting all disk devices: Cannot run program "iostat": error=2, No such file or directory
 ERROR [os-metrics-4] 2015-06-10 10:57:28,234 Long os-stats collector failed: Cannot run program "iostat": error=2, No such file or directory
 ERROR [os-metrics-3] 2015-06-10 10:57:28,234 Long os-stats collector failed: Cannot run program "iostat": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to install iostat on your system, `sudo apt-get install sysstat`  or yum for fedora systems.

Comment: it does seem like that's what's going on, as it ends with `ERROR [os-metrics-3] 2015-06-10 10:57:28,234 Long os-stats collector failed: Cannot run program "iostat": error=2, No such file or directory`